# Retrieving data from curl and json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

I am trying to extract the individual data strings from a curl and json_decode result, but cannot manage to target the array elements correctly:

API:

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

Result:

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.04350003,"Ask":0.04395399,"Last":0.04350003}}
```

PHP:

```
echo 'Bid: '.$obj['result']['Bid'].'<br/>';
echo 'Ask: '.$obj['result']['Ask'].'<br/>';
echo 'Last: '.$obj['result']['Last'].'<br/>';
```

Also tried:

```
echo 'Bid: '.$obj['Bid'].'<br/>';
echo 'Ask: '.$obj['Ask'].'<br/>';
echo 'Last: '.$obj['Last'].'<br/>';
```

Comment: You need to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true if you want to assign the response to a variable - otherwise, it's just echoed to screen

Comment: awesome ! that did the trick ! thanks !

Comment: In the future, debug your code by using `print_r` and `var_dump` on variables to first determine if you even have data in those variables you are working with. This entire thing could have been avoided and reduced to 'why is curl not returning data?' ... leaving the json out of it, and thus the slew of same-answers about json_decode.

Comment: @iainn you should post that as the answer, so rainer can accept it. Otherwise some random newb will post exactly what you said to take the credit ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat I did print_r, that's how I knew what data is returned in the first place :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a true parameter to your json_decode

Like

```
json_decode($execResult, true);
```

Else you get a stdObject with the decoded data.

Then you should be able to use $obj['result']['Bid'] aso.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `json_decode` has an optional second parameter - boolean - that either returns the data as an object or as an array.

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.04350003,"Ask":0.04395399,"Last":0.04350003}}

$obj = json_decode( $execResult ); /* will return an object */
echo $obj->result->Bid;

$obj = json_decode( $execResult, true ); /* will return an array */
echo $obj['result']['Bid'];
```

---

Just ran this as the test..

```
$data='{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.04350003,"Ask":0.04395399,"Last":0.04350003}}';

$obj = json_decode( $data ); /* will return an object */
echo $obj->result->Bid;

$obj = json_decode( $data, true ); /* will return an array */
echo $obj['result']['Bid'];
```

which displayed:

```
0.043500030.04350003
```

Comment: hm, output is empty ... nothing is returned

Comment: it only worked like iainn suggested above, set to CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, this made it work

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
echo 'Bid: '.$obj->result->Bid.'<br/>';
echo 'Ask: '.$obj->result->Ask.'<br/>';
echo 'Last: '.$obj->result->Last.'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

let

```
$json = '{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.04350003,"Ask":0.04395399,"Last":0.04350003}}';

$obj = json_decode($json, true);// decode and convert it in array 

echo 'Bid: '.$obj['result']['Bid'].'<br/>';
echo 'Ask: '.$obj['result']['Ask'].'<br/>';
echo 'Last: '.$obj['result']['Last'].'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json_decode($string, true);` as an array

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult, true);

echo 'Bid: '.$obj['result']['Bid'].'<br/>';
echo 'Ask: '.$obj['result']['Ask'].'<br/>';
echo 'Last: '.$obj['result']['Last'].'<br/>';
```

OR using `json_decode($string);` as an object

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);

echo 'Bid: '.$obj->result->Bid.'<br/>';
echo 'Ask: '.$obj->result->Ask.'<br/>';
echo 'Last: '.$obj->result->Last.'<br/>';
```